# gazebo_ros missing(indigo 14.04)

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,I'm using indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
i have installed **indigo full desktop** version,deleted **Gazebo Ver 2** and installed **Gazebo Ver 6.1.0** from the gazebosim website.
i am now trying to launch a xacro model in gazebo, and the following error occurs:

```
edmond@edmond:~$ roslaunch myrobot_gazebo gazebo.launch
... logging to /home/edmond/.ros/log/a1af2d0c-aa3e-11e5-9405-c81f662b396f/roslaunch-edmond-4794.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
p.start()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
self._start_infrastructure()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
self._load_config()
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 451, in load_config_default
loader.load(f, config, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 730, in load
self._load_launch(launch, ros_config, is_core=core, filename=filename, argv=argv, verbose=verbose)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 702, in _load_launch
self._recurse_load(ros_config, launch.childNodes, self.root_context, None, is_core, verbose)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 666, in _recurse_load
val = self._include_tag(tag, context, ros_config, default_machine, is_core, verbose)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 95, in call
return f(*args, **kwds)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 587, in _include_tag
inc_filename = self.resolve_args(tag.attributes['file'].value, context)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/xmlloader.py", line 183, in resolve_args
return substitution_args.resolve_args(args, context=context.resolve_dict, resolve_anon=self.resolve_anon)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 312, in resolve_args
resolved = _resolve_args(resolved, context, resolve_anon, commands)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 325, in _resolve_args
resolved = commands[command](resolved, a, args, context)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 141, in _find
source_path_to_packages=source_path_to_packages)
File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/substitution_args.py", line 184, in _find_executable
full_path = _get_executable_path(rp.get_path(args[0]), path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 200, in get_path
raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)

**ResourceNotFound: gazebo_ros**

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/edmond/rosws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

so i tried installing **ros-indigo-gazebo-ros**, but then

```
edmond@edmond:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros

   **The following packages have unmet dependencies!:**

    ros-indigo-gazebo-ros : Depends: gazebo2 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libsdformat1 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### does anyone has the idea how to fix this problem?
Thanks a lot!

btw, how to edit the format when posting? i can only see the hints for italic,bold, link and image on the right hand side..thanks again!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223057/gazebo_ros-missing(indigo-14.04)/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions describes how to use a non-default version of gazebo with ROS.

In particular, once you've added the osrfoundation repo to your apt sources, you can install the gazebo ros packages using their version number:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo6-ros-pkgs
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on 2015-12-29**:
Thanks to ahendrix, problem solved.